# Intellij IDEA - Gives 2 types of Step snippets for feature file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, cucumber

I am using Intellij IDEA with Groovy/Java and when I run a fresh feature file the missing step snippets always come in two types

How do I get Intellij to just give me one set?

I have tried changing dependencies and asked around slack

```
Given(/there is a report on interest/) {  ->
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException()
}

@Given("there is a report on interest")
public void there_is_a_report_on_interest() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
}
```

I am looking to only get one of the above type from Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Just an educated guess here: There are two cucumber plugins for IntelliJ IDEA. One that is Cucumber for Java, one that is Cucumber for Groovy. When using code completion, you must specify whether your step definitions are Java or Groovy.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-step-definition.html

I would try specifying which language your step definitions are in, so that IntelliJ knows what language to generate them in. I suspect it is generating in both languages.

Comment: Thanks, the Cucumber for Groovy plugin is dependant on the Cucumber for Java plugin there has to be something else to stop it generating both.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not suggesting you disable any plugins. From the webpage I linked, it states: "**If you opt to create a new step definition file, specify its name, type (Java or Groovy), and the parent directory.**"  It's possible that IntelliJ is unsure what language your step definition file is supposed to be in. Try to create a new step definition file, explicitly define the language, and see if the issue persists.

Edit: Also remember to look at the Run Configuration of your Feature file, and ensure it is only using a single plugin.

Comment: Ahh Okay. Thanks. I will look at that now.

Comment: I have looked over that link. This is used to generate single steps that might have been missed. I am running a full feature file with no stepdefs defined yet and the above code is a small sample of what  runs into hundreds of steps. It's a pain to go through and pick out the set I don't want.